# Fix table formatting from conversion of .doc to .txt

Tags: python, text, doc

I am converting a .doc file into a txt file.
My only problem is that the .doc file contains tables.
In the txt file, these tables are not written line by line. 
Instead, they are written cell by cell.

For example:

[image]

This table should be in txt file like this:

> Terms and Definitions
>
> Dog Has 4 legs
>
> Cat Likes sleeping a lot
>
> Bear Likes honey.

But it's like this instead:

> Terms and Definitions
>
> Dog
>
> Has 4 legs
>
> Cat
>
> Likes sleeping a lot
>
> Bear
>
> Likes honey.

This happens in **every** table that's in my .doc file.

The code i have is this:

```
def doc_to_txt(path_of_file,name_of_file):
    try :
        app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
        app.Visible = True
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path_of_file) :
            for file in files :
                fullpath = os.path.join(*[subdir, file])
                if file== name_of_file :
                        out_name = file.replace("doc", r"txt")
                        in_file = os.path.abspath(path_of_file + "\\" + file)
                        out_file = os.path.abspath(path_of_file + "\\" + out_name)
                        doc = app.Documents.Open(in_file)
                        content = doc.Content.Text
                        print('Converting '+name_of_file+' into txt file for parsing... ' )
                        #print('Exporting', out_file)
                        doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=7)
                        doc.Close()
                        return out_file
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
    finally :
        app.Quit()
```

Comment: Can you post sample doc file?

Comment: @Alderven I am sorry i can't upload the doc file because it's from my work. That's why i deleted the normal table and wrote random stuff on the picture.